# Doxygen Inheritance Diagrams: Template Classes

Tags: c++, inheritance, doxygen, diagrams, template-classes

I currently use doxygen to create documentation for a project. Recently, a small part of this project started using template programming and the resulting inheritance diagrams created by doxygen do not really fit into the rest of the documentation.

A small example:

```
template<class system>
class A{};

template<class system>
class AA : public A<system>{};

template<class system>
class AB : public A<system>{};

class AAA : public AA<int>{};
class AAB : public AA<double>{};
class ABA : public AB<float>{};
class ABB : public AB<bool>{};
```

creates an ineritance diagram of the form

[image]

which is just really difficult to read imo. I would rather like to see a more minimal picture like this

[image]

, skipping the "redundant" classes `A<double>, A<int>, A<float>, A<bool>`. Is there a way to do this?

In my Doxyfile, the only non default settings are

```
HAVE_DOT           = YES
TEMPLATE_RELATIONS = YES
```